# "Sur le weekend" vs. "Le weekend"

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, articles

I am uncertain which of these is proper French form:

> Je vais au café au weekend.
>
> Je vais au café sur le weekend.
>
> Je vais au café le weekend.
>
> Sur le weekend, je vais au café.

Answer (score 2):

> Je vais au cinéma le week-end. (talking about a habit)

ou bien

> Le week-end je vais au cinéma.

sont correctes. Les autres variantes sont incorrectes.

Autre possibilité.

> Je vais au cinéma chaque week-end/tous les week-ends.

Notons la nuance (ce au lieu de le)

> Je vais au cinéma ce week-end. (talking about this weekend)

ou bien

> Ce week-end je vais au cinéma.

Pour un jour on dirait par exemple :

> Je vais au cinéma le(ce) samedi.

Notons qu'il n'y pas de s : samedi et non samedis.

Comment: J’entends aussi souvent "J’irai au cinema du week-end" signifiant "à un moment durant le week-end", mais ne saurait dire s’il s’agit d’un belgicisme...

Comment: +1 pour le commentaire. C'est le premier fois que je l'entends. Peut-être un natif français pourrait vérifier  s'il existe en France.

Comment: Et je constate une énorme faute d’orthographe : "ne sauraiS"... malheureusement le laps de temps pour éditer ses commentaires est trop limité...

Comment: Je suis belge, et je confirme qu'on peut entendre "du weekend" en Belgique. A priori, même en Belgique, cela me semble néanmoins un usage limité géographiquement (j'ai de la famille du côté de Charleroi, et il me semble qu'ils utilisent cette tournure).

Comment: MAIS il me semble que même en français "standard", on peut utiliser "du/de" + une durée de temps dans une tournure négative, pour dire "sur la durée totale de cette période". Ex: "je ne suis pas sorti du weekend", "je ne l'ai pas vu de la soirée". On peut alors préciser "je ne l'ai pas vu de toute la soirée". Un francophone non-belge pourrait-il confimer ?

Comment: @LaurentS. et Greg Je confirme: "J’irai au cinema du week-end" ne se dis pas en Français de France mais "Je ne suis pas sorti du weekend", oui.

Comment: Je confirme l'usage de "de+durée intermédiaire" pour dire à un certain point de cette durée en Belgique. Par durée intermédiaire, j'entends plus long qu'une heure mais plus court qu'un mois: Je vais le faire **dans** la minute ou **dans** l'heure, mais **de** la matinée, **de** la journée, **du** weekend, **de** la semaine, **de** la quinzaine qui vient. Plus long que ça et mon usage varie: **dans** le mois, **dans** l'année, mais **de** l'automne ou **de** la saison.

Comment: @Laurent S. : "J'irai au cinéma du week-end" est en effet un belgicisme, mais il a passé la frontière dans le Nord où cette formule est aussi très commune.

Answer (score 1):

Only this one:

> Je vais au café le weekend.

is proper.